# Xcode database usage confusion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, database

I am new to iPhone app development and have a question about storing data. I've spent quite sometime learning about core data but still confused about the concept of persistence store.

What I understand is that core data is just a way of managing the data you downloaded from an external database. But given that core data is backed by SQLite, does that mean there exists a SQLite db in-memory while running? If so, does that mean when I use core data it will be more effective if I download a huge data set at start? But what about apps such as twitter or Facebook that require constant update of data, is a straight $NSURLConnection$ sufficient in these cases? If core data is used, will the extra overheads (i.e. data objects) be of any burden for such frequent request of update?

I would also like to find out some common ways of setting up an online database for iPhone app? Is it usually MySQL servers with a homemade Python wrapper that translates the data into JSON? Any standard server provider would provide the whole package? Or open source code?

Many many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go through and try to address each of your questions, let me know if I missed one!

Firstly, Core Data can be used to store information generated in your app as well, there is nothing keeping you from using it in one way or another.

The way I understand it working is that the file, or other storage mechanism Core Data uses, exists regardless of whether or not your app is running. For a user to have to wait for a large database to be downloaded and loaded into a local database without being able to interact with your application is not the best way to do it in my opinion, people react negatively unresponsive UI. When a user may run your app for the first time, its possible you may need to get a larger set of data, but if any of it is generic and can be preloaded that is ideal, the rest should be downloaded as the user attempts to access it.

Facebook and Twitter applications work just as you understand in that a connection is established and the information is pulled from the appropriate site, the only thing they store is profile information, as far as I know. I would hesitate to use Core Data to store peoples information as eventually yes, there would be a significant amount of overhead caused by having to store peoples news feed or messages going back months on end.

As for setting up on online database that is something I'm unfamiliar with, so hopefully someone else can provide some insight on that, or if I find something I think may be of use, I will post back here for you. This part may actually merit its own separate question.

Let me know if you need to me elaborate on anything!

Comment: Thanks Karoly. I imagine there could be a sort of mixture of Core data and connection request, is this possible? Speaking of NSURLConnection, do you think RestKit is a good alternative?

Comment: Or perhaps RestKit vs NSJSONSerialization?

Comment: Yes a combination of the two is absolutely possible, I've done an app that worked in that way. I haven't heard bad things about it, but I personally haven't used it. It looks like it'd be a good tool to use. As with RestKit, I haven't used NSJSONSerialization, when I made my app I had just created my own parser because that seemed like the easiest way to do it, though at the moment I dont recall details. If it fits what you need to do for you app and looks fairly stable, I'd say go for it.